# converting Assembler function InterlockedCompareAndStore128() for windows 64 bit to non assembler for Linux 64 bit

Tags: linux, delphi, assembly, x86-64, compare-and-swap

Hi guys i am very new to delphi and in my application there are so many assembler functions which were earlier used for windows (32bit and 64 bit). But as now i am migrating my application from windows to Linux(64bit) asm functions are not supported there .so if anybody can support/help in understanding this asm function.Thanks in advance.

```
function InterlockedCompareAndStore128(var dest, newVal, oldVal) : boolean; assembler;
asm
  push  rbx
  push  rdi
  mov   rdi, rcx            // ptr to dest -> RDI
  mov   rcx, [rdx+8]        // newVal -> RCX:RBX
  mov   rbx, [rdx]
  mov   rdx, [r8+8]         // oldVal -> RDX:RAX
  mov   rax, [r8]
  lock cmpxchg16b [rdi]

  mov   rax, 0
  jnz   @exit
  inc   rax
@exit:
  pop   rdi
  pop   rbx
end;
```

Comment: If you don't have time to understand your code, why do you think we would? At the very least, make an effort.

Comment: The x86-64 System V calling convention would pass value args in registers, if you wanted to port it to a stand-alone asm function instead of letting a C++ compiler generate it.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html for GNU C/C++, or use `std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong`  for one CAS.  Also you can use `setz al` instead of a silly branch over an `inc`.

Comment: Hi @David  there is not only asm functions in my application there are so many other libraries which are tightly coupled with windows and i am making them work by rewriting either in c++ or delphi. Its not about time but i have zero knowledge on asm functions  so hard for me to rewrite it.

Comment: @ASKaur Then grab a book on assembly and learn that!  Stack Overflow is not the right place to pawn off work you can't do yourself.

Comment: "it's not about time" vs "I have very less time to complete", please make your mind up. But yeah, we do expect you to work on this yourself. If you want somebody else to do it, hire someone.

Comment: Thanks @David  i will work on it as i already did some simple asm functions by reading online but felt this little complicated . But fine i will work .

Comment: Could you tell us what your application is doing?

Comment: It is a testing tool with number of protocols support .

Comment: Did you consider porting the app to Lazarus? It supports asm (see [here](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Inline_Assembler)).

Comment: ok I will search little bit on this . have not checked for Lazarus . And i am using Rad Studio 10.3 . Thanks

Comment: However it seems that Windows and Linux have a different ABI (e.g. use of registers), which means you would need to adapt the asm code anyway...

Comment: Yeah, porting/moving from Delphi to Lazarus will not solve the issue. @Olivier is absolutely right about that.

Comment: yes even i was looking for Delphi conversion to Lazarus but also i have to move from Windows to Linux so i think more or less same issues will come forward. But thanks Olivier and Sherlock70