# Error : Invalid Character '(' in mnemonic

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit

Hi I am trying to compile the below assembly code on Linux using gcc 7.5 version but somehow getting the error

> Error : Invalid Character  '(' in mnemonic

```
bool InterlockedCompareAndStore128(int *dest,int *newVal,int *oldVal)
{
asm(
  "push  %rbx\n"
  "push  %rdi\n"

  "mov   %rcx, %rdi\n"         // ptr to dest -> RDI
  "mov   8(%rdx), %rcx\n"      // newVal -> RCX:RBX
  "mov   (%rdx), %rbx\n"
  "mov   8(%r8), %rdx\n"       // oldVal -> RDX:RAX
  "mov   (%r8), %rax\n"
  "lock   (%rdi), cmpxchg16b\n"

  "mov   $0, %rax\n"
  "jnz    exit\n"
  "inc1   %rax\n"
  "exit:;\n"

  "pop   %rdi\n"
  "pop   %rbx\n"
  );
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this . Checked many  online links and tutorials for Assembly code but could not relate the exact issue.
Thanks for the help in advance.

In Windows I could see the implementation of the above function as:

```
function InterlockedCompareExchange128;
asm
      .PUSHNV RBX
      MOV   R10,RCX
      MOV   RBX,R8
      MOV   RCX,RDX
      MOV   RDX,[R9+8]
      MOV   RAX,[R9]
 LOCK CMPXCHG16B [R10]
      MOV   [R9+8],RDX
      MOV   [R9],RAX
      SETZ  AL
      MOVZX EAX, AL
end;
```

For PUSHNV , I could not found anything related to this on Linux. So , basically I am trying to implement same functionality in c++ on Linux.

Comment: There are seven `(`s in that code. Which one is the compiler referring to?

Comment: Have you considered using the [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) that someone suggested to you [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61362027/14215102)? As for the current question the `lock   (%rdi)` doesn't look quite right to me, shouldn't the argument go after the cmpxchg16b?

Comment: @dratenik  in windows the command is lock cmpxchg16b [rdi] (in delphi) which is converted to c++ on Linux, so in Linux the src and dest are opposite for mov  but i am not very sure about lock . May be you are right.

Comment: @dratenik I tried atomic builtins and they worked to get value for 8 byte (64 bits), but I need to have for 16 bytes (128 bits), which  I could not achieve with atomic functions. for example in the above code , the dest parameter should be 16 bytes.

Comment: @molbdnilo currently its pointing to the instruction "mov   8(%rdx), %rcx\n"

Comment: Per the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html): *16-byte integral types are also allowed if ‘__int128’ (see __int128) is supported by the architecture.*.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here was about `Invalid Character '(' in mnemonic` which the other answer addresses.

However, OP's code has a number of issues beyond that problem.  Here's (what I think are) two better approaches to this problem.  Note that I've changed the order of the parameters and turned them const.

This one continues to use inline asm, but uses [Extended asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) instead of [Basic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html).  While I'm of the [don't use inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) school of thought, this might be useful or at least educational.

```
bool InterlockedCompareAndStore128B(__int64 *dest, const __int64 *oldVal, const __int64 *newVal)
{
    bool result;
    __int64 ovl = oldVal[0];
    __int64 ovh = oldVal[1];

    asm volatile ("lock cmpxchg16b %[ptr]"
        : "=@ccz" (result), [ptr] "+m" (*dest),
          "+d" (ovh), "+a" (ovl)
        : "c" (newVal[1]), "b" (newVal[0])
        : "cc", "memory");

        // cmpxchg16b changes rdx:rax to the current value in dest.  Useful if you need
        // to loop until you succeed, but OP's code doesn't save the values, so I'm
        // just following that spec.
        //oldVal[0] = ovl;
        //oldVal[1] = ovh;

        return result;
}
```

In addition to solving the problems with the original code, it's also inlineable and shorter.  The constraints likely make it harder to read, but the fact that there's only 1 line of asm might help offset that.  If you want to understand what the constraints mean, check out [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) page (scroll down to *x86 family*) and the description of [flag output constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands) (again, scroll down for *x86 family*).

As an alternative, this code uses a gcc builtin and allows the compiler to generate the appropriate asm instructions.  Note that this must be built with [-mcx16](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) for best results.

```
bool InterlockedCompareAndStore128C(__int128 *dest, const __int128 *oldVal, const __int128 *newVal)
{
    // While a sensible person would use __atomic_compare_exchange_n and let gcc generate
    // cmpxchg16b, gcc decided they needed to turn this into a big hairy function call:
    // https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80878
    // In short, if someone wants to compare/exchange against readonly memory, you can't just
    // use cmpxchg16b cuz it would crash.  Why would anyone try to exchange memory that can't
    // be written to? Apparently because it's expected to *not* crash if the compare fails 
    // and nothing gets written.  So no one gets to use that 1 line instruction and everyone 
    // gets an entire routine (that uses MUTEX instead of lockfree) to support this absurd
    // border case.  Sounds dumb to me, but that's where things stand as of 2021-05-07.

    // Use the legacy function instead.
    bool b = __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(dest, *oldVal, *newVal);

    return b;
}
```

For the kibizters in the crowd, here's the code generated by `-m64 -O3 -mcx16` for that last one:

```
InterlockedCompareAndStore128C(__int128*, __int128 const*, __int128 const*):
    mov     rcx, rdx
    push    rbx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
    mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rcx]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
    mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
    lock cmpxchg16b XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    pop     rbx
    sete    al
    ret
```

If someone wants to fiddle, [here's](https://godbolt.org/z/G8oh39GTK) the godbolt link.

Comment: Thanks @David . we have implemented  the same functionality using "__atomic_compare_exchange_n " , but nice to see more detailed explanation you gave .

Comment: Glad to see you went to a builtin.  Make sure you look at the disassembly.  If you see a function call instead of cmpxchg16b, you may not be happy with the performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this code, and I'm not convinced I'm doing you any favors by telling you how to fix the specific problem.

But the short answer is that

```
"lock   (%rdi), cmpxchg16b\n"
```

should be

```
"lock   cmpxchg16b (%rdi)\n"
```

Tada, now it compiles.  Well, it would if `inc1` was a real instruction.

But I can't help but notice that the pointers here are `int *`, which is 4 bytes, not 16.  And that this function is not declared as `naked`.  And using Extended asm would save you from having to push all these registers around by hand, making this code a lot slower than it needs to be.

But most of all, you should really use the [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html), like `__atomic_compare_exchange` because inline asm is error prone, not portable, and *really* hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks @David . it compiles but let me try the atomic builtins, as some rror i was getting with __int128 while compiling with Gcc version 7.5 will post you the update soon.

Comment: Also meant to mention: You're using rcx, rdx, r8 as the locations for the parameters.  Pretty sure that's the Windows convention and Linux does something different.  Yet another reason to use builtins.